# in gwt project how to retrive an image which stored as blob and show it on the front page

Tags: image, gwt, blob

below is my code

and how to retrive the image from the datastore and display on the front page,this is a GWT project,the image been stored as Blob,how to transport it to Image?  and anyone can give me an example about the image store and display in a GWT project.

`enter code here`my code:

```
//the User class which the image stored as blob

package cn.hjf.client;

import java.util.Date;   
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class User implements IsSerializable{

@Persistent
private String userName;//用户名

@Persistent
Blob userImage;


@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long userId;

public User(){}

public User(String name,Blob image){
    this.userName = name;
    this.userImage = image;

}

public Blob getUserImage() {
    return userImage;
}

public void setUserImage(Blob userImage) {
    this.userImage = userImage;
}

public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

}

//the servlet which store image 

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    FileItemIterator iter;
try {
    iter = upload.getItemIterator(req);
    FileItemStream imageItem = iter.next();
InputStream imgStream = imageItem.openStream();
// construct our entity objects
    Blob imageBlob = new Blob(IOUtils.toByteArray(imgStream));
        // User user = new User(imageItem.getName(), imageBlob);
    User user = new User("xxx", imageBlob);

    // persist image
    PersistenceManager pm = Persister.get().getPersistenceManager();
    pm.makePersistent(user);
    pm.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}


// respond to query
res.setContentType("text/plain");
res.getOutputStream().write("OK!".getBytes());

//this code segment can retrive the image as Blob

Blob imageFor(String name, HttpServletResponse res) {
// find desired image
 Image image = new Image();
PersistenceManager pm = Persister.get().getPersistenceManager();
Query query = pm.newQuery(User.class);          
List<User> results = (List<User>)query.execute();
image = results.iterator().next().getUserImage();
// serve the first image
res.setContentType("image/jpeg");
try {
    res.getOutputStream().write(image.getBytes());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(image.getBytes());
return image;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a Servlet that call "serve" function on the blobstoreService.

Check the example from google : [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/?hl=FR)

**EDIT:**

You have to Understand the **BlobstoreService Workflow**.

[This tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-gaestorage/index.html?ca=drs) will help you.

I see in your code that you're saving the user image as a Blob. It's better to use url in the the model. (it's more lightweight)

**To summarize :**

**Client Side :** 
You have a FormWidget that set the action field with an upload URL from a service that call `blobServiceInstance.createUploadUrl("/your_upload_Servlet");`
(Don't forget to set the enctype parameter to "multipart/form-data" on the form)

**Server Side :**
You have an UploadServlet like this :

```
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        //this is the value in your input file form
        String uploadType = req.getParameter("uploadType");
        List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobstoreService.getUploads(req).get(uploadType);
        System.out.println("Url of the file : "+ "/serve?blob-key=" + blobKeys.get(0).getkeyString());
```

You have another Servlet that Serve the image :

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws IOException {
        BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
        blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
    }
```

So when you save a user with an image url saved like this :

"/serve?blob-key="ag5ncmVlbi1hbmFseXplcnITCxIGUHJvamV0GICAgICAgMAIDA""

You will get the image on the client side using this url.

Hope it helps.

PS : Sorry for my English :)

Comment: can you give me your code? I have seen the content of this link, but I can not understand it yet. I want use the FileUpload widget of GWT,upload an image and then I can retrive the image and display it on the front page.